# Ionic Status bar hides Header When Call is in progress

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, header, overlapping

I tried increasing header height but it did not work, When call receives I can see header sliding down as expected but it suddenly jumps back up. Any solutions ?

[image: Status bar overwrites Header]

Comment: its the default behavior of ios platform

Comment: So there is no way I can adjust it now?